# How do I customize terminal prompt color?

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization

I can change the background and text color in Preferences, but there is not an option to change the prompt text color, it's always green! Anyway to change it to red?

[image: Terminal]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change on palette menu, and find same color that use on your font. But I don't know why ubuntu doesn't make a description of the colors used for fonts in this menu.

See this image:

[image]

But the above method is not right, because it can replace other colors associated with setting the palette.

Maybe you can edit the .bashrc file at home:
- Open the .bashrc file, look for it (ctrl + f) **#force_color_prompt=yes**, remove the sign (#), and save it.

After that, to change the color, you can search for this script, the .bashrc:

> if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
>       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\033[01;**31**m]\u@\h[\033[00m]:[\033[01;34m]\w[\033[00m]\$
>   ' else
>       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' fi

in the script, I thickened **"31"**. It is a color code. To change the color, you can change the color code. There is a color code reference for this [site](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)

This is screenshot when i change the code with **31**:

[image]

May be useful and Enjoy, CMIIW :)

Comment: Redefining the palette like this does not only change the prompt's color but also the color of many terminal-based applications, likely resulting in ugly or unusable color setups. The intent of this configuration is to find your preferred shade of green for green, not to turn green into magenta.